# Error while uploading image to server with Swift

Tags: swift, post, upload, server, multipartform-data

Hi so here's the code I'm using to upload an image to our server via a link.

```
if (currentElementName == "uploadUrl") {
                let returnUploadURL = string

                var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(pictureImage.image)

                if imageData != nil{
                    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: returnUploadURL)!)
                    var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
                    println(request)
                    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

                    var boundary = NSString(format: "---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449")
                    var contentType = NSString(format: "multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary)
                    //  println("Content Type \(contentType)")
                    request.addValue(contentType, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

                    var body = NSMutableData.alloc()

                    // Title
                    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                    body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image.png\"\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                    body.appendData("Hello World".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)!)

                    // Image
                    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                    body.appendData(NSString(format:"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"image.png\"\\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                    body.appendData(NSString(format: "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n").dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
                    body.appendData(imageData)
                    body.appendData(NSString(format: "\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)

                    request.HTTPBody = body

                    var returnData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: nil, error: nil)
                    var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                    println("returnString \(returnString)")
                }
            }
```

For some reason I get this in the console and the app crashes.

```
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x17020d560> { URL: http://oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE }
returnString Optional(Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => r
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpbAfzYN
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 17263726
        )

)
)
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x174018130> { URL: & }
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

First off, how is it giving it the filename "r"? And why am I getting this fatal error after the "&" in the link? The link works this way.

```
"http://oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE&id=22405"
```

Comment: @JeromeL It's below the code I wrote. Start with "<NSMutableURLRequest:"

Comment: By the way, when you get this immediate issue behind you, you might consider retiring this synchronous request in favor for an asynchronous one. Also, given the problems building a multipart request, you might consider using something like AFNetworking or Alamofire, rather than building requests yourself.

Comment: Thanks @Rob, I will consider. Would you have any idea as to why Xcode decided to have issues with the link after the "&" symbol? Even the console returns it in a new line away form the actual link.

Comment: It's hard to say. You haven't shown us the code that builds the `string` that you assign to `returnUploadURL`. I suspect the bad URL being passed to the request rests there, not in the above code. Below you suggest you were parsing a SOAP response. Perhaps there's a problem in your parsing code (e.g. creating request in `foundCharacters` rather that `didEndElement`). Hard to say without seeing the relevant bits.

Comment: @Rob Hmm I wish I could show you some how because it's hard one to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. In your `content-disposition` for the image name, you have `\\r` where you obviously meant `\r`.
2. Your request is not terminated properly. You should have a `--` after the last boundary, but before the `\r\n` (e.g. the format string for that last boundary should be `\r\n--%@--\r\n`).
3. Regarding your failed request, it would appear that this is being called a second time, but that the second `returnUploadURL` is incorrect (it would appear to be simply `&`). You don't show us how you built that URL, but it seems there's a problem there. Check the code that is building that URL.

   If you do a `println` of the URL before you start building the request, it should bring that problem into stark relief. You suggest the URL should be:

   ```
   http://oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE&id=22405
   ```

   But, somehow, there appear to be two separate requests being built. Your first request appears to be cutting off the URL before the `&`. The second seems to be the `&` itself. Bottom line, you haven't shared the code that builds the URLs, but I suspect some issue there.

Comment: I saw that, I noticed that the first part of the URL stays the same (oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE) and parsed the SOAP response to get the id and just did "http://oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE&id=\(returnUploadID)" But I wish I didn't have to hard code the the link.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing an address that doesn't exist (`URL: http://oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE`) to `sendSynchronousRequest`.

`sendSynchronousRequest` returns `nil` if a connection could not be created.

Thus, `returnData` is set to `nil` an you are trying to unwrap it on the next line:

`var returnString = NSString(data: returnData!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)`

This cause the error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

What you need to figure out is why `returnUploadURL` is set to `URL: http://oms/process.php?method=PQUEUE_INV_FILE`. I guess this part happens earlier in your code.